# Sails.js execute a middleware just before the controller action

Tags: sails.js

I am developing an installable sails-hook that injects some checking on the request before allowing it to pass through the controller action. I want the checking to be done via installable hook, not as a policy, as I will be using the hook in other projects as well.

So, I am doing something like this inside my hook

```
sails.on('router:before', function() {

    //attach middlewares here

    sails.router.bind('/route', function(req, res, next) {

    //do checking here. if everything is fine, call next()
    req.options.controller // ?

    }
});
```

The problem with the above apporach is that the `req.options` object does not contain the `controller` and `action` properties that my `middleware` depends upon (not now, may be in future).

So, what is the bestway to achieve this? One possible solution is to explicitly attach a policy that executes the middleware. I am looking for better options. Thanks

Comment: why just not create middleware and add it to middlewares pipeline?

Comment: In the middlewares the req.options is still empty, so this is not a decision.